# why slice indices error is occurred during summation part of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an XML file and I try to trace it and extract some features. I need to sum part of a list but when I used the following code it produced this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\UGC\xml_feature_main.py", line 117, in <module>
    XML_feature_Calculation(dir_main)

  File "E:\UGC\xml_feature_main.py", line 47, in XML_feature_Calculation
    QPY_framesum[2]+=sum(QPY_float[j*Number_MBLK_per_frame:(j+1)*(Number_MBLK_per_frame-1)])

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I also change the type of `Number_MBLK_per_frame` to float but I do not know what is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
def XML_feature_Calculation(dir_main):
    os.chdir(dir_main) #change directory to downloads folder
    files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
    fnames_main = [x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".xml")]
    feature=np.zeros((2000,9))
    QP_Y_frame=np.zeros((3,1))
    QPY_framesum=np.zeros((3,1))
    QPY_framenum=np.zeros((3,1))
    for i in range(len(fnames_main)):  
        GOP_MV_avg=0
        print(i)
        pname= (fnames_main[i])
        root = ET.parse(pname).getroot()
        PBI=list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('Picture/SubPicture/Slice/Type'))
        MB_size=list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/TypeString'))
        
        QPY=list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('Picture/SubPicture/Slice/MacroBlock/QP_Y'))
        QPY_float=[float(j) for j in QPY]                      
        frame_Num=list(qpy_node.text for qpy_node in root.findall('Picture/SubPicture'))                   
        Number_MBLK_per_frame=float(len(QPY)/len(frame_Num))
        for j in range(len(frame_Num)):
            if PBI[j]=="0":#p_frame
                QPY_framesum[0]+=sum(QPY_float[j*Number_MBLK_per_frame:(j+1)*(Number_MBLK_per_frame-1)])
                QPY_framenum[0]+=1
            if PBI[j]=="1":#b_frame
                QPY_framesum[1]+=sum(QPY_float[j*Number_MBLK_per_frame:(j+1)*(Number_MBLK_per_frame-1)])
                QPY_framenum[1]+=1
            if PBI[j]=="2":#I_frame
                QPY_framesum[2]+=sum(QPY_float[j*Number_MBLK_per_frame:(j+1)*(Number_MBLK_per_frame-1)])
                QPY_framenum[2]+=1
        QPY_P_frame=QPY_framesum[0]/(Number_MBLK_per_frame*QPY_framenum[0])
        QPY_B_frame=QPY_framesum[1]/(Number_MBLK_per_frame*QPY_framenum[1])
        QPY_I_frame=QPY_framesum[2]/(Number_MBLK_per_frame*QPY_framenum[2])
        QPY_framenum.fill(0);
        QPY_framesum.fill(0);
        
        
    return
current_path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd());
current_dir = Path.cwd()
all_sub_dir_paths = glob(str(current_dir) + '/*/') # returns list of sub directory paths
all_sub_dir_names = [Path(sub_dir).name for sub_dir in all_sub_dir_paths] 
for i in range(len(all_sub_dir_names)):
    dir_main=current_path+'\\'+all_sub_dir_names[i]+'\\'+'gop_split'+'\\'+'xml'+'\\'
    XML_feature_Calculation(dir_main)
```

Comment: The error is quite clear, the indices need to be integers. Your formulae for the indices involve multiplying `Number_MBLK_per_frame`, which you make a float in the line `Number_MBLK_per_frame=float(len(QPY)/len(frame_Num))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempted correction went the wrong direction. The problem is not that `Number_MBLK_per_frame` is *not* a float, the problem was that *it was already* a float and you need it to be an integer instead.

I think you want:

```
Number_MBLK_per_frame = int(len(QPY) / len(frame_Num))
```

Or better yet, avoid making a float in the first place by using integer division with the `//` operator:

```
Number_MBLK_per_frame = len(QPY) // len(frame_Num)
```